# See what causes deadlock on pthread_mutex_lock

Tags: xcode, multithreading, core-data, lldb

I have a Core Data iOS app that uses private queue concurrency in a background process. I'm getting a deadlock that makes the UI freeze up from time to time (fairly regularly, to be honest) - but all the info I get from the debugger (LLDB) is that it is stuck on pthread_mutex_lock. The stack trace is no longer than that, which makes debugging near on impossible:

```
thread #1: tid = 0x2503, 0x3b5060fc libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 24, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
frame #0: 0x3b5060fc libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 24
frame #1: 0x3b44f128 libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_mutex_lock + 392
```

The XCode process pane is similarly only showing those two entries on the stack.

I'm quite new to this multithreading stuff so am at a total loss where to begin with fixing the issue. Any suggestions for how to go about debugging this?

Comment: There's not really enough information in this to answer it.  Locks like this happened when using NSFetchedResultsController on iOS 5 as it took a lock on the parent context that it shouldn't have - then caused the background context to get into a deadlock situation when it was trying to save via the parent context.  But in your particular case there's not enough to go on in here.

Comment: My question is "How do I go about debugging it?" I don't really have any more information than you about what causes it!

Comment: Look in the other threads in the debugger and see what points they are stopped at - if there's a locking situation that would indicate there are two other things waiting to get the resource that's locked - so you should get stack traces of the other things waiting. If you can't see anything in the debugger, it's a matter of putting NSLog statements throughout your code and watching the console to see what is logged when it happens. You can add the code you're using for working with the background context here and someone might spot something amiss - though this is often easier said than done.

Answer (score 2):

Your stack is obviously longer than two frames, you can't start a thread with pthread_mutex_lock.  So the truncation of the stack frame is pretty clearly just a bug in the lldb unwinder.  If you have an ADC account, please file a bug about this at bugreporter.apple.com.  Also if you're not using the most recent version of lldb you can get your hands on you might want to try that, maybe it fixed whatever bug you are seeing.  You can install multiple Xcode's side by side so you don't have to remove the one you are currently using to try a newer one.

You might also try another tool that will give you a backtrace (e.g. the Instruments time profiler) when your app gets into this state, since it uses a different unwinder.  That will at least let you see what the full backtrace is.